# how to center align a group of radio buttons under the center of the quiz title and keep responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

here is the code to reproduce the issue in bootstrap3. 
what I want is to align the radio buttons below the center of the quiz title, while keeping text align left. 
current title is inline flow by default bs3 sample form structure. 
i'm thinking if using 
`position absolute; or display:block/inline-block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;  display:flex; methods etc.` might break the responsive flow. any suggestions how you balance responsive and align nicely ?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="main-content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
    <h3 class="quiz-title" style="">Question: Do you think it's easy to center align the radio button groups and keep bootstrap responsive.</h3>
  </div>
  
 
  <div class="col-xs-12   ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="Q2[score]" class="">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2[score]" value="1" required="required">Agree
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12   ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="Q2[score]&quot;" class="">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2[score]" value="2" required="required">Neither Agree nor Disagree
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="radio">
        <label for="Q2[score]" class="answered">
          <input type="radio" name="Q2[score]" value="3" required="required">Disagree
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear-both" style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
    <button type="button" class="NextQuizBTN btn btn-default">NEXT</button>
  </div>


  </div>
</div><!--end of container-fluid-->  
 
  </div>
</body>
```

I received some suggestions among below answers for making it appear like center aligned in bootstrap3, however I also found some pitfalls using the above method , listed in below picture I roughly made.

Both the **Answer text** in radio label and the **Quiz Title** text length are Variable, so this is the tricky part in this case to make it center aligned while keep responsive using css.

[image: The effect produced by using col-sm-offset-* and below it, the Expected Effect regardless of how label text length changes]

Comment: add .radio class {text-align:center;}

Answer (score 0):

Add Some CSS

```
.radio{display:inline-block;}
```

Add Class radio parent div to `col-xs-12` with `text-center`

Comment: do you mean this https://jsfiddle.net/a6j7p0et/2/
but it made all elements aligned center , i would prefer the group container of radio buttons align center, while keeping text inside to be left-aligned.  or would you explain it more clearly.

Comment: what about adding class=center-block to div class=form-group and then adding 
<style>
.center-block {
    margin: auto;
    width:20%;
    
    
}
</style>

Comment: remove text-center change class "col-sm-12" to "col-sm-7" & add class "col-sm-offset-5"  https://jsfiddle.net/a6j7p0et/3/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the class "col-xs-12" to "col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4" to center it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a6j7p0et/6/

take a look at the above suggestion using the "col-sm-7" & add class "col-sm-offset-5" class setting , however,  the col-xs-offset-* method seems unable to be intellegent enough to fit for text with different length.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by wrapping all your radio button divs inside a parent div. And then placing this div accordingly to the device using `offset`.

```
 <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-7 col-md-offset-5">
   //.. all your radio buttons div's inside this
 <div>
```

Below is the working snippet. Have a check.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h3 class="quiz-title" style="">Question: Do you think it's easy to center align the radio button groups and keep bootstrap responsive.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="hidden" name="Q2[cat]" value="Conscientiousness">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="hidden" name="Q2[POST_ID]" value="88">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-7 col-md-offset-5">
          <div class="col-xs-12   ">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="radio">
                <label for="Q2[score]" class="">
                  <input type="radio" name="Q2[score]" value="1" required="required">Agree
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12   ">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="radio">
                <label for="Q2[score]&quot;" class="">
                  <input type="radio" name="Q2[score]" value="2" required="required">Neither Agree nor Disagree
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="radio">
                <label for="Q2[score]" class="answered">
                  <input type="radio" name="Q2[score]" value="3" required="required">Disagree
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear-both" style="clear:both;"></div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
          <button type="button" class="NextQuizBTN btn btn-default">NEXT</button>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of container-fluid-->

  </div>
</body>
```